# Python: Pandas - Delete the first row by group

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following large dataframe (`df`) that looks like this:

```
    ID     date        PRICE       
1   10001  19920103  14.500    
2   10001  19920106  14.500    
3   10001  19920107  14.500     
4   10002  19920108  15.125     
5   10002  19920109  14.500   
6   10002  19920110  14.500    
7   10003  19920113  14.500 
8   10003  19920114  14.500     
9   10003  19920115  15.000
```

**Question:** What's the most efficient way to delete (or remove) the first row of each ID? I want this:

```
        ID     date     PRICE       
    2   10001  19920106  14.500    
    3   10001  19920107  14.500     
    5   10002  19920109  14.500   
    6   10002  19920110  14.500    
    8   10003  19920114  14.500     
    9   10003  19920115  15.000
```

I can do a loop over each unique `ID` and remove the first row but I believe this is not very efficient.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use `groupby/transform` to prepare a boolean mask which is True for the rows you want and  False for the rows you don't want. Once you have such a boolean mask, you can select the sub-DataFrame using `df.loc[mask]`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID': [10001, 10001, 10001, 10002, 10002, 10002, 10003, 10003, 10003],
     'PRICE': [14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 15.125, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 15.0],
     'date': [19920103, 19920106, 19920107, 19920108, 19920109, 19920110,
              19920113, 19920114, 19920115]},
    index = range(1,10)) 

def mask_first(x):
    result = np.ones_like(x)
    result[0] = 0
    return result

mask = df.groupby(['ID'])['ID'].transform(mask_first).astype(bool)
print(df.loc[mask])
```

yields

```
      ID  PRICE      date
2  10001   14.5  19920106
3  10001   14.5  19920107
5  10002   14.5  19920109
6  10002   14.5  19920110
8  10003   14.5  19920114
9  10003   15.0  19920115
```

---

Since you're interested in efficiency, here is a benchmark:

```
import timeit
import operator
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID': np.random.randint(100, size=(N,)),
     'PRICE': np.random.random(N),
     'date': np.random.random(N)}) 

def using_mask(df):
    def mask_first(x):
        result = np.ones_like(x)
        result[0] = 0
        return result

    mask = df.groupby(['ID'])['ID'].transform(mask_first).astype(bool)
    return df.loc[mask]

def using_apply(df):
    return df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda group: group.iloc[1:, 1:])

def using_apply_alt(df):
    return df.groupby('ID', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x[1:])

timing = dict()
for func in (using_mask, using_apply, using_apply_alt):
    timing[func] = timeit.timeit(
        '{}(df)'.format(func.__name__), 
        'from __main__ import df, {}'.format(func.__name__), number=100)

for func, t in sorted(timing.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    print('{:16}: {:.2f}'.format(func.__name__, t))
```

reports

```
using_mask      : 0.85
using_apply_alt : 2.04
using_apply     : 3.70
```

Answer (score 43):

Another one line code is `df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda group: group.iloc[1:, 1:])`

```
Out[100]: 
             date  PRICE
ID                      
10001 2  19920106   14.5
      3  19920107   14.5
10002 5  19920109   14.5
      6  19920110   14.5
10003 8  19920114   14.5
      9  19920115   15.0
```

Comment: why we need two `1:` here in `[1:, 1:]`?

Comment: The second 1: is unnecessary. It means take from the second column (since the first column is 0) until the end.  You can simply do group.iloc[1:].

Answer (score 11):

Old but still watched quite often: a much faster solution is nth(0) combined with drop duplicates:

```
def using_nth(df):
    to_del = df.groupby('ID',as_index=False).nth(0)
    return pd.concat([df,to_del]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

In my system the times for unutbus setting are:

```
using_nth       : 0.43
using_apply_alt : 1.93
using_mask      : 2.11
using_apply     : 4.33
```

Comment: Thanks, `.nth()` is great!
Got your code two times faster, still, though:
`return df.drop(df.groupby('ID',as_index=False).nth(0).index)` (1.49 ms ± 90.2 µs instead of 3.13 ms ± 11.8 µs).

Answer (score 5):

The fastest solution I've found is generating a column with the group-observation number and then erasing all observations with `value = 0`.

```
df['num_in_group'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount()
df = df[df['num_in_group'] > 0]
```

or

```
df = df[df.groupby('ID').cumcount() != 0]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://%5Bandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) by column `ID`:

```
df = df[df.duplicated('ID')]
print (df)
      ID      date  PRICE
2  10001  19920106   14.5
3  10001  19920107   14.5
5  10002  19920109   14.5
6  10002  19920110   14.5
8  10003  19920114   14.5
9  10003  19920115   15.0
```