# How to delete the first line of each group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this :

```
   id  values
0   1       3
1   1       6
2   1       3
3   2       7
4   2       6
5   2       3
6   2       9
```

And I want to delete the first line of each group based on `id`,the result should like this:

```
   id  values
1   1       6
2   1       3
4   2       6
5   2       3
6   2       9
```

I tried  it done by: `df = df.groupby('id').agg(lambda x:x[1:])`,but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me?Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Pandas - Delete the first row by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226142/python-pandas-delete-the-first-row-by-group)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with `iloc`:

```
df = df.groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x:x.iloc[1:])
#also working, not sure if generally
#df = df.groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x:x[1:])
print (df)
   id  values
1   1       6
2   1       3
4   2       6
5   2       3
6   2       9
```

Or [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['id'].duplicated()]
print (df)
   id  values
1   1       6
2   1       3
4   2       6
5   2       3
6   2       9
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['id'].duplicated())
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
Name: id, dtype: bool
```

Comment: what is group_keys

Comment: @pyd - good question - for avoid Multiindex in `groupby.apply`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
df.loc[~df.index.isin(df.drop_duplicates(subset='id').index)]
```