# How do you remove first row of each groupby aggregate dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I currently have this function:

```
def process_data(data):
    data = data[data['Bucket Number'] == 25.0].groupby(['Activity Month', 'Agent Sign']).agg({'Total Ping Current Forecast': [np.sum]})
    data = data.sort_values(['Activity Month', ('Total Ping Current Forecast', 'sum')], ascending=[True, False]).groupby(level=0).head(3)
    return data
```

Which produces this output:

```
                          Total Ping Current Forecast
                                                  sum
Activity Month Agent Sign                            
202001         {Various}                 1.305513e+09
               HDQGR1                    2.171435e+08
               CRCTLD                    4.774614e+07
202002         {Various}                 1.159181e+09
               HDQGR1                    1.912536e+08
               CRCTLD                    4.573402e+07
202003         {Various}                 1.090292e+09
               HDQGR1                    1.852591e+08
               CRCTLD                    4.045673e+07
```

**I want to remove the first row of each group so that the output looks like this:**

```
                          Total Ping Current Forecast
                                                  sum
Activity Month Agent Sign                            
202001         HDQGR1                    2.171435e+08
               CRCTLD                    4.774614e+07
               DFW1DF                    1.622023e+07
202002         HDQGR1                    1.912536e+08
               CRCTLD                    4.573402e+07
               HDQ1ZB                    2.711470e+07
202003         HDQGR1                    1.852591e+08
               CRCTLD                    4.045673e+07
               HDQ1ZB                    1.532134e+07
```

Essentially, I want the highest value of each group dropped since the dataframe is already sorted in descending order by `sum`.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50486098/how-to-delete-the-first-line-of-each-group-in-pandas) and tried this:

```
def process_data(data):
    data = data[data['Bucket Number'] == 25.0].groupby(['Activity Month', 'Agent Sign']).agg({'Total Ping Current Forecast': [np.sum]})
    data = data.sort_values(['Activity Month', ('Total Ping Current Forecast', 'sum')], ascending=[True, False]).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1:]).groupby(level=0).head(3)
    return data
```

But it only applied the function to the first group giving this result:

```
                          Total Ping Current Forecast
                                                  sum
Activity Month Agent Sign                            
202001         HDQGR1                    2.171435e+08
               CRCTLD                    4.774614e+07
               DFW1DF                    1.622023e+07
202002         {Various}                 1.159181e+09
               HDQGR1                    1.912536e+08
               CRCTLD                    4.573402e+07
202003         {Various}                 1.090292e+09
               HDQGR1                    1.852591e+08
               CRCTLD                    4.045673e+07
```

**How do I apply that function to each group in the dataframe?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Pandas - Delete the first row by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226142/python-pandas-delete-the-first-row-by-group)

Answer (score 0):

In your code instead of finishing with `.head(3)` you could use `.nth([1, 2])`.

This would return the second and third elements from every group, as the index for `nth` is zero-based.

Read more in [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth)