# Pandas: Delete percentage of dataframe dependent on value change in other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I have a very large dataframe (about 5 billion rows and 13 columns). One of the columns can have values of 0 and 1, representing inactive and active mode. There are usually several rows of inactive mode (0), followed by rows of active mode (1). So first there is an inactive segment, followed by an active segment, again followed by an inactive segment and so forth.

Something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(30, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['E'] = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]

    A   B   C   D  E
0   53  27  10  49  0
1   39  46  89  33  0
2   32  43   7  15  0
3   16  36  33  18  0
4   12   3  94  96  1
5   31  22  64  51  1
6   79  93  93  67  1
7   85  27  10  19  1
8    4  92  38  38  1
9   79   8   6  90  1
10  68   6  26  24  1
11  89  49  23  91  1
12  44  17  40  75  1
13  12  18  17  87  1
14  76  67  74  15  0
15   9  37   8  92  0
16  52  53  93  47  0
17  74   3  27  96  0
18  77  10  93   8  0
19  64  33  46  79  0
20  72   9  36  99  0
21  75  13  76  49  1
22  95  21  88  77  1
23  46  45  36  20  1
24  61  26  72  48  1
25  35  62  98  28  1
26  91  43  23  42  0
27  25  59   6  30  0
28  20  31   2  76  0
29   2  25  86  12  0
```

I need to delete the first 20% of every active segment, the inactive segments should stay as they are. So it should look like this:

```
    A   B   C   D  E
0   53  27  10  49  0
1   39  46  89  33  0
2   32  43   7  15  0
3   16  36  33  18  0
6   79  93  93  67  1
7   85  27  10  19  1
8    4  92  38  38  1
9   79   8   6  90  1
10  68   6  26  24  1
11  89  49  23  91  1
12  44  17  40  75  1
13  12  18  17  87  1
14  76  67  74  15  0
15   9  37   8  92  0
16  52  53  93  47  0
17  74   3  27  96  0
18  77  10  93   8  0
19  64  33  46  79  0
20  72   9  36  99  0
22  95  21  88  77  1
23  46  45  36  20  1
24  61  26  72  48  1
25  35  62  98  28  1
26  91  43  23  42  0
27  25  59   6  30  0
28  20  31   2  76  0
29   2  25  86  12  0
```

I already added an additional column using df.diff() that shows where the change from inactive to active and vice versa occurs:

```
     A   B   C   D  E  E_diff
0   53  27  10  49  0     NaN
1   39  46  89  33  0     0.0
2   32  43   7  15  0     0.0
3   16  36  33  18  0     0.0
4   12   3  94  96  1     1.0
5   31  22  64  51  1     0.0
6   79  93  93  67  1     0.0
7   85  27  10  19  1     0.0
8    4  92  38  38  1     0.0
9   79   8   6  90  1     0.0
10  68   6  26  24  1     0.0
11  89  49  23  91  1     0.0
12  44  17  40  75  1     0.0
13  12  18  17  87  1     0.0
14  76  67  74  15  0    -1.0
15   9  37   8  92  0     0.0
16  52  53  93  47  0     0.0
17  74   3  27  96  0     0.0
18  77  10  93   8  0     0.0
19  64  33  46  79  0     0.0
20  72   9  36  99  0     0.0
21  75  13  76  49  1     1.0
22  95  21  88  77  1     0.0
23  46  45  36  20  1     0.0
24  61  26  72  48  1     0.0
25  35  62  98  28  1     0.0
26  91  43  23  42  0    -1.0
27  25  59   6  30  0     0.0
28  20  31   2  76  0     0.0
29   2  25  86  12  0     0.0
```

I can't figure out how to determine the length of the segments and then delete the correct rows. Do I need to write a loop for that or is there an easier way? And how can I determine the correct index values for the rows to drop?

Comment: This should get you halfway there, your question is just a variation of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45886579/7483211

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job. It's a patchwork of two separate StackOverflow answers: [stackoverflow.com/a/45886579/7483211](http://stackoverflow.com/a/45886579/7483211) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/31226290/7483211:

```
df['flag'] = df.E.diff().ne(0).cumsum()

def mask_first(x,ratio=0.2):
    result = np.ones_like(x,dtype=bool)
    result[0:math.ceil(len(x)*ratio)] = False 
    return result

mask = df.groupby(['flag'])['flag'].transform(mask_first).astype(bool)
df[(df.E == 0) | mask].drop('flag',axis=1)
```

The output is:

```
idx A   B   C   D   E
0   77  44  52  17  0
1   75  61  69  6   0
2   79  87  99  31  0
3   42  10  3   98  0
6   53  68  86  92  1
7   25  3   27  84  1
8   18  60  93  79  1
...
```